# Issue for linking external CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have tried too many times to link the css file externally but it doesn't work yet. It is working fine with internal css and inline css but not with external css. I have checked too many times the name, location, and folder of that file but still not find any solution. Here are some codes of mine.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Webpage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Samar/s.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<img src="samar.jpg" width="300" height="370" align="right" alt="My Image"/>
<h1><center><i>  Welcome to Samar Club  </i></center></h1>
<p>  Hello Everyone, My name is Samar. I am here to give you guys the solutions of NCERT Maths problems.</p>




</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css file

```css
h1{   
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 37px; 
     border: 12px double grey;  
       color:maroon;
     }
p{     
      text-align:right;
      font-family:sans-serif;
      font-weight:bold; 
      font-size:25px;
      margin-top:35px;
      background-color:yellow;
     }
```

Comment: Will you show your folder structure and the actual directory? Will you check the browser console if there is an error locating the file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't have enough fingers and toes to count [the number of times this question gets asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linking+external+CSS+file) and [all over the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linking+external+CSS+file&t=chromentp&ia=web) with the exact same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your css file path.

1. First make sure you have saved your css file with the .css extension.
2. If your both html file and the css file reside same folder, then use the css file path as `href="s.css"`.
3. If your html file and the css file reside different folders, give the path to the css file from the location where html file resides.
   Ex: css file resides ParentFolder -> CssFolder -> s.css. Html file resides ParentFolder -> HtmlFolder -> a.html. Then use the path to the css file as `href="../CssFolder/s.css"`.